# Change a src link address from png to gif when a user hovers over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my JS

```
script type="text/javascript">

  var src = $('Pic').attr('src');
  $('Pic').hover(function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.png', '.gif'));
    }, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src);
    });
  });
</script>
```

And here is my Image button:

```
<input id="Pic" type="image" src="BeerButton1.png" alt="Submit" width="600" height="600" style="top: 15%; position: absolute; left: 30%;" />
```

Comment: You're missing the `#` in front of `Pic` to target the proper selector.

Comment: I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } '

Comment: Omit the last `});`, as you've already closed your click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var src = $('#Pic').attr('src');
    $('#Pic').hover(function(){
         $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.png', '.gif'));
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: do you have jQuery included ?

Comment: How would i add that to a website done on notpad, Add the jquery file to my folder and then add its link?

Comment: Just put this in your `<head>` --  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Copied the jquery file and saved it and added the ref:  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

and i get that pic does not have .attr

Comment: Even referencing your way, i get:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #Pic has no method 'attr'

Answer (score 1):

calls to jQuery need to be wrapped in:

```
$(function(){ // do stuff })
```

This is short-hand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { // do stuff });
```

Also, in case you have more than one of these images, instead of holding a var outside of the hover() definition, just swap either way between png and gif.

So...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){        
    $('#Pic').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.png', '.gif'));
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.gif', '.png'));
    });
})
</script>
```